# I can't get my navbar sub menu to align vertically

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, submenu

Please can someone help, I've been at this for 2 days and just can't get it right! I'm trying to create a dropdown menu to adhere to my existing navbar. Here's my code below. I have it set that the navbar style changes for smaller windows/mobile and still need to figure that part out wrt the sub menu.. HELP :(

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color: #666;
}
nav.black ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
  filter: invert(50%);
}

.menu-icon {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #00b4ff;
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 900px) {
  .nav-logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
  }

  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #000;
  }

  nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
  }

  .showing {
    max-height: 45em;
  }

  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <nav>
        <div class="menu-icon">
          <i class=" fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">PADI Experiences</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PADI Basic Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PADI Speciality Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PADI Pro</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="small-nav-logo"><a id="nav-africa" href ="index.html"><img src="img/logo-icon.gif" alt="Home" width="80" height="68"></a></li>
            <li><a href="dives.html">Dives</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Guided Packages</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="nature.html">Nature</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add some more descriptions about your problem it is not clear that what is your expected result/

Comment: `max-height: 0px`. What is this for?

Comment: The max height is set to back to 0 for the small windowed option, there is a different navbar style for windows smaller than 900px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your css.

```
nav ul li ul li{
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

All you needed to do was target the `li` inside the `li`.

Comment: Bless your soul! I feel really stupid now haha, it was so simple, can't believe I missed it! But I am still learning, I've only been coding html for 3-4 months now!

Comment: Happy Learning <3